# JComponent with JButton togather

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcomponent

I have a problem using JComponent and JButton togather.

```
public class GameWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    private javax.swing.JLabel freeCardLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel NewGameBody2;
    private Game game;

    public GameWindow (int rozmer, int numberOfPlayers, int numberOfTreasures){       
        /*create a mazeboard*/
        game = new Game();
        game.newGame(rozmer, numberOfPlayers, numberOfTreasures);



        /* the graphic rendering */
        JFrame gameWindow = new JFrame();
        gameWindow.setSize(1000, 730);


        /* create panel for button*/
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        /* create button */
        JButton button = new JButton("OK");   
        //button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        //button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
        buttonPanel.add(button);
        buttonPanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 700));
        gameWindow.setContentPane(buttonPanel);


        GameComponent GC = new GameComponent(rozmer, game);
        gameWindow.add(GC);


        gameWindow.setTitle("Labyrinth - The Game");
        gameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameWindow.setVisible(true);
        gameWindow.setResizable(false);
        gameWindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);


    }
```

this is my GameWindow class. I would like to have something like that:

[image: my game]

while GameComponent GC = new GameComponent(rozmer, game); will draw the Labyrinth. With the code posted above the button will display only without labyrinth.

GameComponent is using simply:

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        image = null;
        offset = calculateOffset(rozmer);
        super.paintComponent(g);


        /* draw the whole field */
        for (int i = 0; i < rozmer; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < rozmer; j++){                
                selectImage(i, j);
                g.drawImage(image, offset+150+j*63+j*1, offset+63*i+i*1, this);
            }
        }
        /* draw free card */
        selectImage(-2, -2);
        g.drawImage(image, offset+270+(rozmer-1)*63, offset+63*(rozmer-1)-50, this);
    }
}
```

and extends JComponent class.

I would like to have both button and my Labyrint in one window. Can anyone help me please? Thank you so much.

EDIT: After overriding getPreferredSize() in GameComponent it paint both, altough the Labyrinth is cut and button is in the middle right :(

Comment: Have you overridden `GameComponent.getPreferredSize()` to return something sensible? Currently it should be right of the button (because the `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` by default), but zero size unless GC has a preferred size.

Comment: I havent, I will get on it and post here the result.

EDIT: Ok now it is printing the button and the component but I dont know how to place it correctly, can you give me a hint? How much return from getPrefferedSize from gameComponent? And how to place the button right? Thank you.

Comment: The preferred size depends on what you consider to be the correct size for the game area - probably depends on the labyrinth size. As for the layout, a very useful resource is the [visual guide to layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) - and remember you can nest layouts, so that you don't need to find a layout manager that does the complete window layout. Combining them is the normal way of using them.

Comment: Yes 700x700 but how can I put it into center and the button into the right panel? I shall use BorderLayout, right?

Comment: `BorderLayout` is a viable choice for the main layout. The tutorial should have a link how to use `BorderLayout` (as well as for other layout managers).